# Have a function converting to its name when printed

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-conversion

I have an array of functions, but when I print the array I get a pretty ugly output:

```
[<function f1 at 0x7f708c2bf1b8>, <function f2 at 0x7f708c2bf230>, <function f3 at 0x7f708c2bf2a8>]
```

Is there a kind of magic trick to have those functions to have a string equivalent? A compact output like this:

```
[<f1>, <f2>, <f3>]
```

Or:

```
['f1', 'f2', 'f3']
```

Comment: Those functions do have a string equivalent. The string is `<function name at hexaddr>`.

Comment: `[function.func_name for function in functions]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *already* looking at the string equivalent; the value is produced by `repr()` (always used for all container contents):

```
>>> def f1(): pass
...
>>> repr(f1)
'<function f1 at 0x10232d320>'
```

The output is meant for *debugging* purposes, not for end-user presentations; the hex address is the `id()` for that object, and helps you distinguish between otherwise similarly named functions. If you want to produce 'user friendly' output, do your own formatting. You could use a list comprehension, for example; each function object has a `__name__` attribute you could use for that:

```
['<{}>'.format(func.__name__) for func in list_of_functions]
```

This is still a list, so each value is still shown as a debug value, but now of strings:

```
>>> list_of_functions = [f1, f2, f3]
>>> ['<{}>'.format(func.__name__) for func in list_of_functions]
['<f1>', '<f2>', '<f3>']
```

Use other string techniques to further transform that as needed. Adding commas with `str.join()` for example:

```
>>> ', '.join(['<{}>'.format(func.__name__) for func in list_of_functions])
'<f1>, <f2>, <f3>'
```

Comment: Looks to me like you may have mistakenly repeated `['<{}>'.format(func.__name__) for func in list_of_functions]`,

Comment: @martineau: uhm, no, all 3 occurrences of that expression serve a purpose in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the name:

```
lst = [func1,func2,func3]
print([f.__name__ for f in lst])
```

with output:

```
['func1', 'func2', 'func3']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need something more complex than `func.__name__`, you can wrap it in class and implement `__repr__`:

```
class FuncProxy:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{self.func.__name__}>'.format(self=self)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.func()



def some_func(): pass

l = [some_func, some_func, some_func]
l = [FuncProxy(i) for i in l]

print(l)  # [<some_func>, <some_func>, <some_func>]
```